# Why does the definition $id = 1 need?

Tags: powershell

I try to customize my profile on Windows PowerShell.

Referring a book, I wrote the following code in `Microsoft.Powershell_profile.ps1`.

```
function Prompt
{
    $id = 1
    $historyItem = Get-History -Count 1
    if($historyItem)
    {
        $id = $historyItem.Id +1
    }

    Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkGray "`n[$(Get-Location)]"
    Write-Host -NoNewLine "PS:$id > "
    $host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = "$(Get-Location)"
    "`b"
}
```

I can understand most of how the code works, but not understand the `$id = 1` (line 3).

Why does it need this code? $id is defined in line 7, so `$id = 1` isn't need here, is it?

So, I try to execute this code and the without `$id = 1` code. To me, there's no difference.

[image: the upper: with $id = 1, the lower: without $id = 1]

Why is `$id = 1` added to this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is needed if `$historyItem` is not defined. Another way to write the same function, maybe this is more clear:

```
function Prompt
{
    $historyItem = Get-History -Count 1
    if($historyItem)
    {
        $id = $historyItem.Id +1
    }
    else
    {
        $id = 1
    }

    Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkGray "`n[$(Get-Location)]"
    Write-Host -NoNewLine "PS:$id > "
    $host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = "$(Get-Location)"
    "`b"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just want to point out that it can also be written in a more terse way like this:

```
$id = if($historyItem) { $historyItem.Id +1 } else { 1 }
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't required. The code you posted needs it because it needlessly distinguishes between "has history" and "doesn't have history". If you removed the line `$id = 1` and started a new PowerShell instance you'd have an empty `$id` as long as the command history remains empty.

You could get the same result as the code from your question by simply running

```
$id = (Get-History -Count 1).Id + 1
```

because `(Get-History -Count 1).Id` evaluates to an empty result if the history is empty, which is automatically cast to 0 for the addition operation.